# How can I see a variable's value for debugging VHDL code in modelsim?

Tags: vhdl

I want to see a variable's value for debugging my code. But, I can see only signals and input and outputs value when I put mouse pointer on them, like in this picture (`state` is a signal here):

[image: I can see signal's value]

But, I can't see value of the variable `tmp`:

[image: I cannot see variable's value]

How can I see also the value of variables?

Comment: Copy the variable onto a signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can oberserve the variable value by single-stepping through the respective `process`.

1. Start the simulation and open the source file containing the respective `process`.
2. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `process` and run the simulation until the breakpoint is triggered with the command `run -all`.
3. Now, you can observe the variable value by

   a) hovering the mouse over it, or by

   b) selecting menu View -> Locals and navigating to the process in the design hierarchy.
4. Now, you can single-step through the process with the command `step`. You will see, how the variable value changes until the process suspends. Continue the simulation with `run -all` until the breakpoint is triggered again.

Answer (score 3):

There's one way:

> i) Run the simulation for a very short time, eg 1 ns.
>
> ii) Click on View -> Locals
>
> iii) Navigate to the point in your design where the variable is and
>   you will see it in the Locals window. Add it to the Waves.
>
> iv) Run the rest of your simulation.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing whether there was some other way.

Comment: There is no need to run the simulation for a very short time first. The simulation needs just to be started. Another way is single-stepping as described in my answer.